# Сколькими способами это можно сделать?

Tags: комбинаторика

**Само задание:**

Клетчатая доска 9×9 покрашена в шахматную раскраску (то есть доска покрашена в чёрный и белый цвета; любые две клетки, соседние по
 стороне, имеют разный цвет). Требуется поставить 8 белых ладей так,
чтобы все они стояли на клетках одного цвета и никакие две из них
 не били друг друга (одна ладья бьёт другую, если она стоит с ней в
 одной вертикали или горизонтали). Сколькими способами это можно
 сделать? Расстановки, отличающиеся друг от друга поворотами, симметриями и пр. считаются различными

**Подсказка для него (нашел в интернете):**

Пусть угловые клетки - белые.

1) Ладьи на белых клетках.
Удаляем одну из 9 горизонталей, где ладьи не будет. Поскольку горизонтали различаются, выделим два случая, в зависимости от первой клетки горизонтали: а) белая, б) чёрная.
Далее проходим по белым горизонталям, выбирая место для ладей: на первой из белых горизонталей - 5 мест, затем - 4 места и т. д. Аналогично поступаем с чёрными горизонталями.

2) Ладьи на чёрных клетках.
Аналогично. Частично можно свести к предыдущему пункту.

**Пробовал решать :**

Для первой ладьи - 8 вариантов, для второй - 7 вариантов и т. д. В итоге 8!

Еще раз пересчитал. Число расстановок 8-ми ладей на одноцветных полях равно 9*5!*4!+5*5!*4!=14*5!*4!=8!(первое слагаемое отвечает за цвет, совпадающий с цветом угловых клеток, второе - за другой цвет)

Потом у меня получилось посчитать это по-другому: 9 способов убрать 1 лишнюю горизонталь * 9 способов убрать лишнюю вертикаль (т.к. ладей 8, то на поле 9*9 всегда такие лишние найдутся) * кол-во способов расставить их по чёрным и по белым клеткам (т.е. 4! + 4!), получим 9*9 * (4! + 4!) = 3888 способов.

Позже исправил : 9*9 * (4!*4! + 4!*4!) = 93 312(по белым на поле 8*8 кол-во способов 4! * 4! + аналогично для чёрных)

Я уже запутался со всем этими расчетами , помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Число расстановок на белых полях это число сочетаний из 40 по 8.

Comment: @becouse, с чего бы? Написано же, что они не должны бить друг друга.

Comment: @Qwertiy это общее число расстановок. Автор не с того начинает. Есть 40 способов поставить 1 ладью. Далее вторую мы можем поставить на оставшиеся 32,31, или  или 30 полей и т.д.

Comment: @becouse не могли бы решение на задание написать?я вот свои попытки написал)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала посчитаем количество способов размещения 8 взаимно не атакующих ладей на черных клетках, а затем посчитаем количество способов их размещения на белых клетках.

Предположим, что строки доски пронумерованы от 1 до 9 сверху вниз. (1,1) - черная клетка.

Сначала заметим, что ладья, помещенная на черную клетку в нечетном ряду, не может атаковать ладью на черной клетке в четном ряду.

Это эффективно разделяет черные клетки на доску размером 5×5 (O) и доску размером 4×4 (E)  и ладьи могут быть размещены независимо друг от друга на этих двух досках.  (см. рисунок)

На клетки, O можно разместить ладьи 5! способами и 4! на клетки E.
Это дает 5!4! способов разместить 9 взаимно не атакующих ладей на черных квадратах и удаление любой из этих 9 ладей дает одну из желаемых конфигураций.

Таким образом, есть 9*5!4! способов разместить 8 взаимно не атакующих ладей на черных квадратах, используя очень похожие рассуждения, мы можем разделить белые квадраты.

Белые квадраты разделены на две доски размером 5×4 таким образом, что ни одна ладья на квадрате O не может атаковать ладью на квадрате E.  (см. рисунок)

Максимум 4 ладьи могут быть размещены на доске 5×4 и они могут быть размещены 5*4*3*2 = 5! способами. При этом есть (5!)^2 способов поставить 8 взаимно не атакующих ладей на белых квадратах.

Итого есть 9*5!4! + (5!)^2= 40320 способов разместить 8 взаимно не атакующих ладей на квадратах одного цвета.

Если (1,1) белый квадрат, то рассуждения меняются местами, а общее количество не изменяется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в профиле похожая задача)помогите решить

Comment: задача тоже на похожую тематику с названием темы: 
"Найти все натуральные числа n > 1"